# Computing the number of monomials of a certain polynomial

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, conjectures

I have computed the number of monomials of the polynomial:

$$\prod_{0 \le k_1 \lt \ldots \lt k_{n-t} \le n-1} \left( \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} x^{k_j} \right)$$

with $t = 1$ for $n=2,3,4,5,6$ and found it equal to $1,5,11,19,29$ respectively.

Each factor is a combination of $n-t$ monomials chosen among $1,x,x^2,\ldots,x^{n-1}$. The product is over all possible combinations.

For example, with $n=3$ we have:

$$P(x) = (1+x)(1+x^2)(x+x^2) = x^5 + 2 x^4 + 2 x^3 + 2 x^2 + x$$

and therefore there are $5$ monomials.

Looking at OEIS, one could for example conjecture that the number of monomials is:

$$n-2+(n-1)^2 = n^2-n-1$$

Is the conjecture true?
In general, is it possible to find a formula as a function of $n$ for any given $t$ such that $n \gt t \ge 1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We simply need to find the highest degree that appears. To find this, note that when $t=1$, each sum of monomials will only remove one $x^i$ term, where $0\leq i \leq n-1$. As there are ${n \choose n-1}=n$ such terms, $n-1$ with highest degree $n-1$ and 1 with highest degree $n-2$ (which is precisely the term $\sum_{i=0}^{n-2} x^i$), the term with the highest degree appearing is $x^{(n-1)^2+n-2}$.

Comment: But how can we be sure that all the other terms $x, x^2, \ldots, x^{(n-1)^2+n-3}$ are present?

Comment: Fair question. I think you can do a sort of greedy algorithm approach. i.e., for any $r$ between $1$ and $(n-1)^2+n-2$, how many $n-1's$ are there? Say there are $a_{n-1}$ many. We know then that $0\leq a_{n-1}\leq n-1$. Then, $0 \leq r - a_{n-1}(n-1) < n-1$. So our coefficient of $x^r$ is at least 1. Namely, the one where we choose $a_{n-1}$ many $x^{n-1}$'s from any of the $n-2$ sums which have this term, choose $x^r$ from the 1 sum which does not have $x^{n-1}$, and 1 from all the other sums.

Comment: For your other question about if there is a general formula for any given $t$ such that $n > t \geq 1$, i think you can do a similar analysis of trying to find a general formula for the highest degree, and try seeing if every term appears via a similar argument? i'd have to work it out a bit more myself to be convinced this happens but I think that is a worthwhile avenue